# Is there a naming convention for variables that hold one of several possible ids?

Tags: coding-style, variables, identity

Sorry if this is a silly question, but I am not a native english speaker and a lot of times it is difficult for me to come up with meaningful variable names.

I have a table of users in our app. All of the following columns in the table are unique:

- userid (numeric)
- username (must contain at least one letter)
- email

I want to create a variable that holds "userid or username or email". This variable is basically a unique identifier for the user, since all of the columns are unique and I can easily distinguish what column to search by performing some simple lexical analysis on the variable.

A unique id is usually called "id" in most languages :) But I don't want to call it "id" because it will become ambiguous with the numeric id.

This property/variable will possibly be in hundreds of different forms, so I really don't want to change all of them later. Is there a standard naming convention for such identifiers?

Comment: *"This variable is basically a unique identifier for the user"* - `unique_user_id`?

Comment: What about `key`?

Comment: no ther eis no convention. when in doubt user a longer name. ie. userIdOrEmail

Comment: It’s not a unique identifier since the user has three identifiers.

Comment: @gnasher729  :-)  You are being mean.

Comment: In C this would be a union type, in Pascal it's a variant record. Unless you are really need to trade speed for space, using the same variable to hold one of three different things without a discriminant to tell you which type of of value you are holding is not a good idea. Parsing a value to determine its type is not fast. (And according to your description mad@mike would be a valid username and a valid RFC5322 email...)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to present an answer in case there was some confusion (since you said English isn't your first language).

If you mean that you want to COMBINE `user_id`, `username`, and `email`, this is called a **composite key**. So a `user` with data `{user_id: 1, username: 'erik', email: 'erik@gmail' }` would have a composite key of `1erikerik@gmail` for example.

However, if you really do mean you want to have a data type that will hold each of these values, then the commenters are correct, there isn't really a name for this (that I can think of).That said, you might find this useful: I would decorate those attributes with something like a `Searchable` class or something in the `User` class. Like:

```
public class User {
  Searchable<int> UserId { get; set; }
  Searchable<string> UserName { get; set; }
  Searchable<string> EmailAddress { get; set; }

 public User(int userId, userName, emailAddress) {
  UserId = Searchable<int>.new(userId);
  # and so on
```

Whether or not putting that much effort into it is up to you, just thought I'd offer some food for thought.